# Find a mistake game! Matrix determinant using block matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

I need your help finding where is my mistake while calculating 5x5 matrix determinant using block matrices.

My calculations are 
[image]

I tripple checked everything and the online calculation of matrix A gives determinant of 4. And I get -8 using block matrices.

I just can't see why am I getting wrong answer.

Please help!

EDIT:
The formula I am using is:
det(AD-ACA^(-1)B)
A being

```
0 1
1 0
```

B is

```
0 -2 1
3 1 1
```

C

```
1 -1
2 2
3 1
```

D

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 2
```

Det of part A is -1.

Comment: Can you describe your approach? What formula are you using?

Comment: I have inserted your calculations as an inline image.

Comment: You can't replace $A$ with $-1$ to end up with $-D\pm CB$.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get this correctly this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the first step. If you write your matrix as $\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ C & D\end{pmatrix}$, you claim that the determinant equals $\textrm{det}(-D-CB)$. However, the [correct formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) is $\textrm{det}(A)\textrm{det}(D-CA^{-1}B)$.

Comment: Yep, I understood it as well while editing more information. Thanks!

Comment: With $-D+CB$ you end up with the wrong answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the formula $$\det {\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}}=\det(AD-BC)$$ where $A,B,C,D$ are not square matrices.

This is false in general. The formula holds if they're square matrices(in particular) and there is a commutation condition between $C$ and $D$.